# Command 'swift build' - infinity building

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, perfect

I've downloaded example project from this http://perfect.org/docs/gettingStarted.html and commands, `swift build` and next `swift package generate-xcodeproj` working great.

Than I want to add another package to `Package.swift` file, for example `Perfect-Mustache` and `Postgres-StORM`

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "PerfectTemplate",
    targets: [],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 2),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/SwiftORM/Postgres-StORM.git", majorVersion: 2),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Mustache.git", majorVersion: 2),
    ]
)
```

but than `swift build` from console take forever and I must kill the process after couple of hours.

[image]

Anyone have idea why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some days ago. I resolved it by:

1. Upgrading to Swift 4 and making sure the `swift` command is version 4
2. Making sure your packages from PerfectlySoft are the latest version (majorVersion 3). I would also look up the latest releases from your other packages to make sure they're up-to-date (Postgres-StORM is also at majorVersion 3 now)

Also I suggest you add the `-v` command so you can see any underlying issues

Hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, in my case the problem was conflicting dependencies:

```
.Package(url:"https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MySQL.git", majorVersion: 2)
.Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Session-MySQL.git", majorVersion: 3)
```

What i did not know was, Perfect-Session-MySQL.git had already Perfect-MySQL dependency in it and it was pointing to major version 3.

So please make sure to check out each package's dependencies if there is any conflict.